# PayPal - adaptive payment - mini browser opens blank

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to integrate PayPal adaptive payment flow in my site. I am using following code in my angular application.

Now when I click on "Pay" button, mini browser window opens but it is blank, I am expecting to see PayPal login screen. Any clue for a possible issue?

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay" target="PPDGFrame">
<input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="mini">
<input id="paykey" type="hidden" name="paykey" value="AP-XXXXXXXXXXX"> 
<input type="submit" id="PPsubmitBtn" value="Pay">
</form>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/apdg.js"></script>
<script>
var dgFlowMini = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlowMini({trigger: 'PPsubmitBtn', callbackFunction: 'updateOrder'});

function updateOrder() {
     //My order stuff update code goes here
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: You do realize that PayPal Adaptive Payments is a limited release product ?? Please read this note >>> Important: Adaptive Payments is now a limited release product. It is restricted to select partners for approved use cases and should not be used for new integrations without guidance from PayPal.

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for your comments. Yes I do understand that adaptive payments is now a limited release. However, in our case we want payer to send a payment to payee. We are not the one who receives the payment. Hence looking for adaptive payment. Let me know if you are aware about any alternative. Thanks.